Flask action is not redirecting to the specified html page
I am using flask in pycharm to create a simple website. I am working on features that allow the user to register an account for the website and login using their created credentials. My problem currently is that the registration form isn't consistently redirecting to the login page. It is only refreshing the page after providing a username and suitable password.
Heres what i've currently tried.
Registration HTML Form:

<form method="POST" action="{{url_for('register')}}">
        <!-- Defines username Fields -->
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required><br><br>
        <!-- Defines password Fields -->
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required><br><br>
        <!-- Defines Register Button -->
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>

Login HTML Form:

<form method="POST" action="{{url_for('login')}}">
        <!-- Defines username Fields -->
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required><br><br>
        <!-- Defines password Fields -->
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required><br><br>
        <!-- Defines Login Button -->
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>

Web Page Routes for both login and registration blocks:
from datetime import date
import re
from flask import Flask, render_template,  request, redirect, url_for, session

# Calls the imported flask function and sets to render the web pages in the "template" form
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='template')
app.secret_key = 'your_secret_key'

#User Data and variables being used
users = [{'username': 'password'}]
#Password Complexity
PASSWORD_REGEX = r'^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{12,}$'

# Defining the website routes
@app.route('/')
# Sets up registration page for the site
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    '''Function that renders the registration page'''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Establishes the username and password variables to be inputted into the form
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        if username in users:
            # Refreshes the page and prints a message when username already exists.
            return render_template('register.html', message='Username already exists.')
        if not re.match(PASSWORD_REGEX, password):
            # Refreshes the page and prints a message when password isn't complex enough
            return render_template('register.html', message='Password complexity not met.')

        users[username] = password
        # Redirects to the login screen
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

    return render_template('register.html',date=date.today())

# Sets up login page for the site
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    '''Function that renders the login page'''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Establishes the username and password variables to be inputted into the form
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']

        if username in users and users[username] == password:
            session['username'] = username
            # Redirects to the home page screen
            return redirect(url_for('home_page'))
        # Refreshes the page and prints a message when username already exists.
        return render_template('login.html', message='Invalid credentials.')
    #Renders the login page
    return render_template('login.html',date=date.today())


Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

HTML for login and for registration looks very similar - maybe you put wrong HTML in file login.html

The fact that there is no redirection to login page and staying in register page means that it's passing in one of these cases :
if username in users:
        # Refreshes the page and prints a message when username already exists.
        return render_template('register.html', message='Username already exists.')
if not re.match(PASSWORD_REGEX, password):
        # Refreshes the page and prints a message when password isn't complex enough
        return render_template('register.html', message='Password complexity not met.')

It's rendering the register template with a message,  but the problem is that you are not displaying the rendered message in the register template so that it shows it to you.
Solution : assuming that you are using flask built in jinja templates, you can display the message this way, note that I added some style to make it clear in the browser :


<form method="POST" action="{{url_for('register')}}">
    {% if message %}
        <div style="margin: 1em 0;padding: 1em;background: #cae6f6;border: 1px solid #377ba8;">   {{message}} </div> <br><br>
    {% endif %}
    <!-- Defines username Fields -->
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required><br><br>
    <!-- Defines password Fields -->
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required><br><br>
    <!-- Defines Register Button -->
    <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>



